# Am I able to use rolled hearts when attacking a monster in Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

When attacking a monster in Tokyo, do I get to keep any of the hearts that I rolled if that monster leaves, or are they forfeit?

Answer (score 5):

You heal because movement into Tokyo only happens after the dice have finished resolving.

---

There are five phases to a turn.

1. Roll Dice
2. Resolve Dice
3. Enter Tokyo
4. Buy Power Cards
5. End of Turn

Monsters yield Tokyo when resolving dice in the second phase.

> If you are outside of Tokyo and you roll {Claw}, all  Monsters  who  are  in  Tokyo  lose {Heart} (Tokyo City and Tokyo Bay). These Monsters can then decide to Yield and leave Tokyo or stay. Monsters who Yield Tokyo still lose {Heart}.

But the active player only enters in the third phase.

> If no one is in Tokyo, you must enter and place your Monster in Tokyo City.

---

Even if attacking somehow forced you to enter Tokyo, you could still Heal by applying the effect of the hearts before applying the effect of the claws.

> You can resolve your dice in any order, but you must resolve all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the turn order, all dice affects are resolved before the Move phase, which would move you in if they left.

1. Attack (monster may, if they choose, leave after this)
2. Heal (with any hearts, before or after the attack)
3. Any other dice (or do any of the above in a different order if you want)
4. Move phase, if Tokyo is empty, move in

So, in other words, yes, you still heal either way (on this turn). Not necessarily because of the order you apply the dice effects in, but because you don't move in *immediately* after they leave—you move in during your Move phase which is later in the turn.

However, if there are any special card effects that would damage you *during* the attack as retaliation, it might be a good idea to apply those hearts first so you don't die. (Or after if you were at full health and want to heal up any damage you took during the attack.) But that's a rare case.